# Query about Thawte certificate

Tags: java, java-me, signing, thawte

Does anyone know about whether Thawte certificate certifies once for the entire app or I need to certify every time I release a version for the same application.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a code-signing certificate you can sign as many apps/versions with it as you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you register with Thawte, you have to send them your certificate and choose a validity period (one year or more). They will give you your certificate signed with theirs. You have to add it to your keystore where your private key is.
You can use that certificate to sign as many midlets as you want of any applications as long as it is a valid certificate. Once the certificate expires, you have to renew it with Thawte.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually the thawte cert will expire and you'll need to renew it to continue signing apps. Order it for two years and save some money. Much less expensive ordering thawte code signing from a distributor rather than thawte direct. Give us a try, we're very easy to work with.